# Optimizations to be had for numpy/scipy splines over large TIFF stack ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

So I'm trying to remove *all* background from *all* frames of a TIFF stack. Basically, I want to fit a spline for every row for every frame.

I know there are also ways to correct for local background to reduce overhead with naive background "rings" around located samples to quickly do it for multiple frames, as well as some sort of background fitting (where the uses I've heard of are quite slow).

My version is this:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline as Spline

def timeit(method):
    times = []
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        times.append((te - ts) * 1000)
        print('%r  %2.2f ms' % (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000))
        return result
    return timed

# Generate something that resembles a video
img = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 2**16, size = (10, 500, 400))
img = img/(2**16) # convert to (0,1)

@timeit
def spline_background_subtract(arr, deg, s):
    frames, rows, columns = arr.shape
    ix = np.arange(0, columns) # Points to evaluate spline over

    frames = []
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        frame = img[i, :, :]
        ls = [Spline(ix, frame[i, :], k = deg, s = s)(ix) for i in range(rows)]  # Fit every row with a spline to determine background
        new = np.row_stack(ls)  # Stack all rows
        frames.append(new)
    return frames

frames = spline_background_subtract(arr = img, deg = 2, s = 1e4)

# new_video = np.reshape(np.dstack(frames), newshape = (img.shape))
```

This takes about 50 ms per frame on my computer, but if I have 1000 frames and 100 movies, this quickly adds up if corrections should be done in real-time.

I've tried to trim it as much as possible. Is there anywhere to gain anything, besides rewriting everything in a high performance language?

**EDIT**

Some testing:

- `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` is about twice as slow...
- `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian` is about twice as fast it seems! It does a very good job if the features to be isolated are relatively small (in my case they are), as they'll be smoothed out at smaller standard deviations (= faster computation).

Comment: You can use a much faster uniform filter to aproximate the Gauss-Filter. http://nghiaho.com/?p=1159 Additionally you can work with reduced resolution. (downsample, blur,upsample)

Answer (score 1):

Without benchmarking it myself, I would guess that this line is perhaps the culprit:

```
ls = [Spline(ix, frame[i, :], k = deg, s = s)(ix) for i in range(rows)]
```

If you could vectorize that operation you would get a speedup. You could also try something like this [2d bspline in scipy:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep) which could be faster.

Could also look into Cython / Numba

Comment: I just tested out `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` to interpolate over the entire 2D array at once. Strangely enough, it seems to be twice as slow as looping and splining through rows!